# How can I use the ternary operator in the bash script?

Tags: bash, conditional-operator

I want to generate an output in a bash script that is dependent on a previous input.

The input is stored in the variable OPTION. It can be 1 or 2.

After the input a text should follow:

```
oname = ${OPTION} == 1 ? "OPTION ONE" : "OPTION TWO";
echo "Your selection was: ${oname}" ?
```

But I got this error: `line xx: ==: comman not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The ternary is only for arithmetic. It's unavailable in any other context; you can do `oname=$(( option == 1 ? 2 : 3 ))`, but that's basically the _only_ thing it's good for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok. Thank you for info. is there an alternative or do i have to build a classic if else condition for this?

Comment: The linked duplicate shows you some options, like `case` statements. In a lot of circumstances an associative array (bash's version of what some other languages call "dicts" or "maps") might be appropriate too, with keys for the valid option names.

Comment: If for example you actually had three options and a default, you might have `options=( [1]="OPTION ONE" [2]="OPTION TWO" [3]="OPTION 3" )`, so you could check whether `[[ ${options[$OPTION]} ]]` is true, use that value if it's nonempty, or use your default otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy All right and thank you very much! I had already thought about an array and that is what I will do. Greetings!

Comment: This can be an option : `test "${OPTION}" = 1 && oname="OPTION ONE" || oname="OPTION TWO"`